# Is it viable to use GraphQL to access a sort of 'markdown database'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, graphql

I'm looking to create a web-app that will have a database of a few hundred items. I like the speed of React, and have worked with GraphQL before in Gatsby, so I was wondering if it would make any sense to just create a JSON markdown page with objects containing the items I'll be storing, and using GraphQL to grab the JSON for me to use in the website. My only hesitation in starting this is the obvious scalability issues (although I don't see the database growing to more than a thousand items) and I'm nervous to put a lot of time into this, only to find out there was an easier way.

Perhaps my biggest pull to doing it this way is just my familiarity with the JAM stack. I haven't had much experience with a 'separate' database since my only other strong understanding language is Ruby on Rails, with it's built in API structure.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a typical item you would have in your database?

Comment: Each object would basically be a "genre" of items, for example, one object could be "Chairs" containing sub-objects that have details about specific chairs. {type: 'Wood', function: 'Rocking', brand: 'Redwing'} Similar to how a SQL database is set up, except all in JSON, and it would all be accessable through a single variable with GraphQL's help. The idea is that this allows a more compact app that doesn't require API calls to a database, just it's own internal Markdown database.